# Precisely determine the actual consumed watt of the device

Tags: watts, device

What is the actual consumed watt of the device stated a value of input watt and a value of output watt which we often see it?

Comment: Get a quality meter and record exactly what is used.

Comment: You will also need to study the definitions and relations between energy (in Joule) and energy consumpltion per second (Power in Watt). I say this as you write "consumed watt" which is incorrect, the **rate** at which the **Joules** are consumed is expressed in Watt.

Comment: The consumed power is the input wattage. This is what you will be billed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context missing in question...

Often the "input wattage" in the question is ridiculously large to cover tolerances, maximum input voltage, and the momentary surge of power when you plug an appliance in.

Its use is : connect this appliance to a circuit rated for AT LEAST this power. (Wire size, fuse, breaker rating, etc).

There is no expectation that the appliance will consume more than this, but it may consume much less.

Output wattage will be the output power it can produce. If it's operating at full power, the input power will be greater than this according to the device efficiency. So an 80W output device, 80% efficient, may consume 100W.

Actual consumed power is neither of these.

My laptop PSU input rating is 100-240V, 1.5A AC. That would suggest, 150 to 360W.

Its output rating is 20V 4.5A DC, or 90W.

It is mildly warm, so it is clearly not wasting 360-90=270W!

In actual fact as I am typing this answer, it is consuming 24.1W (as measured by the appliance in Transistor's answer)

Comment: "*My laptop PSU input rating is 100-240V, 1.5A AC. That is, 150 to 360W.*" No, it's a switched mode power supply. It will draw highest current when supply voltage is at minimum (100 V). As supply voltage increases the input current will decrease.

Comment: @Transistor That is the whole point : this is a rating; not an actual power measurement. In fact the initial surge current may be HIGHER thanks to the higher voltage even though the operating input current is lower. Slight rephrase for clarity

Answer (score 1):

> Precisely determine the actual consumed watt of the device.

Some devices consume a fixed power when on - e.g., a heater, a light bulb, a fan - because the load is constant. Usually you can read the power from the rating label - e.g., 2000 W for a heater. Note that this rating is at the rated voltage so if the voltage changes the power will vary too.

Other devices' power consumption will vary - e.g., a washing machine has motors and heaters which turn on and off at various times, and computers will consume more power at high processor and graphic card loading.

You have two options:

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical plug-in power meter. Image source: Amazon.*

- Measure the power consumption using a power meter.
- Use the rating label as a guide figure. In the case of a power supply you use the input power for the calculation as that's what you are paying for.

Comment: Also, many appliances have an energy rating that is provided as part of the specs and perhaps on a placard. For example, [this](https://www.canadianappliance.ca/product/Samsung_RF27T5501SR_French_Door_Refrigerator_Samsung_RF27T5501SR.html#tab-specs)  Samsung refrigerator: ENERGY STAR® Certified Yes Energy Consumption 746 kWh/Year